# Read git hosted jks file in springboot

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to enable mutual authentication in my springboot cloud application. For this I've created public and private jks files. I'm storing these jks files in application only which works fine. But I want to keep these jks files on git repo and bind to springboot application during startup. For local env I'm doing this,

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=s3cr3t
server.ssl.key-password=s3cr3t
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:server.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=s3cr3t
```

how can we achieve this using git repo to store these jks files

Comment: There's nothing automated to do this. You could probably write a `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration` to do it.

Comment: Are you using Spring Cloud Services - Config server?